# Restrict partial access in an excel shared file in sharepoint

Tags: permissions, excel, restricted-access

I have an excel file that has many users but I would like to restrict access to sort or modify the format. Is this possible?

**Update**:

This is a shared file with about 200 employees adding new data daily. We has a situation where someone sorted but did not expand to include all and saved the data. I would like to restrict this type of function if possible.

Comment: This is a shared file with about 200 employees adding new data daily. We has a situation where someone sorted but did not expand to include all and saved the data. I would like to restrict this type of function if possible.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do anything with Excel content from SharePoint security. The only thing you can accomplish is granting access just for viewing the file or for modifying it.
If you are thinking about doing something in the Excel file itself like any macro or something like that, check which type of files are available to be modified in Excel Services. If I remember well, Excel files with macro are not supported.

Comment: This is correct, you can not limit what users can do within the file itself.  Your options within SharePoint are to let users read the file only, or edit the file.  If the user can edit the file they can do anything within the file.